# Javascript: window.saveAs in android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-webview

I am using this code to save client-generated PNG files:

```
my_canvas.toBlob (function (blob) {window.saveAs (blob, my_filename)}, 'image/png')
```

I'm using these for cross-browser compatibility:

1. JavaScript Canvas to Blob 2.0.5 by Sebastian Tschan, https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob.
2. FileSaver.js by Eli Grey, http://eligrey.com.

Works perfectly in IE10+, Chrome, Firefox, Chrome Android, but breaks down in the base web view engine in 4.3. Since I'm trying to lightly use Phonegap here and make it compatible with somewhat non-new current devices mobile, I need it to work in the Android WebView 4.3, at least.

Q & A:

Q: How does it break down?

A: Sends me to a non-existent URL instead of making an image and opening it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had many problems with canvas, blobs and old versions of android.

On some version you have to use BlobBuilder, on others WebKitBlobBuilder (on some versions BlobBuilder is there but not correctly implemented), Canvas.toDataURL is not present before android 3 and does not work correctly before 4.x...

For all those reasons I finally used the [Canvas2ImagePlugin](https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin.git) for android devices and now my app works even in android 2.3.

You can keep your code with browser by testing window.canvas2ImagePlugin and using it if it's found and continue to do what you've been doing if it's not.

Comment: I added it to my Phonegap build online. The website says I have it the plugin installed, version 2, but window.canvas2ImagePlugin is still undefined. I copied in https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin/blob/master/plugin.xml verbatim.. Did you use Phonegap for this? What else do I need to do?

Comment: I'm using it locally, not with phonegap build. But it is listed in the phonegap build compatible plugins. Did you add this line to config.xml? `<gap:plugin name="org.devgeeks.canvas2imageplugin" />`

Comment: Apparently I needed to add the phonegap.js script tag to the top (before changing the base href), and "org.apache.cordova.file". Now it does work, but there is no preview and it creates a random name. Better than nothing, I suppose.